# A method which moves first item in array list to the end

Tags: java

I need to write a method called MoveToEnd which moves the first item in an ArrayList to the end of that list in java

[image]

```
void MoveToEnd()
{
.......


}
```

Comment: Excellent.  Which part of this is causing you a problem?

Comment: please share the code what you have tried ? it willbe easy to build on your solution.

Comment: sorry using stack overflow for the 1st time. i tried attaching the image of code but it did not upload with my question :(

Comment: @PriyaPoOkyGovender Please don't post code as an image. Paste it into your question and click the '{ }' icon to format code.

Answer (score 1):

In case of ArrayList you could use:

```
list.add(list.remove(0));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, OP is not using ArrayList, but is developing her own list class, so this won't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

first,remove the first element "T t = remove(0)"
second,use "add(t)" method

Comment: OP is developing her own list class, which doesn't have these methods (yet).

Comment: 1.new a List   2.for each old List

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework for you, but I can tell you the broad steps you'll have to implement.

Since you're not using the Java ArrayList class, but developing your own version, you'll have to do some low-level manipulation of the array itself.  You'll have to

- copy element 0 to some kind of temporary variable,
- copy all the other elements in the array back by one space in the array (you can use the `System.arraycopy` static method for this),
- put the element that's referred to by your temporary variable back as the last element in the array.

Comment: hi there dawood. thank you for ur comment. i understand it better now. actually this was an exam question and there is no memo for it. which is why i asked here.